# DynamoDB errors Orleans

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, orleans

I have an application running that gets data from IoT devices, I have started to have problems where my Orleans silo freezes completely, and it only starts again when I pres enter on the command line. When I pres enter it usually presents with some dynamodb errors (I use DynamoDB for persistent storage).
I am getting multiple errors with Writing, reading, and check failed exceptions such as:

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.d__16.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.d__16.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.d__2`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.d__7`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.d__10`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>          at Orleans.Persistence.DynamoDB.DynamoDBStorage.d__16.MoveNext()

Write error:

```
fail: Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage[102203]
      Error from storage provider DynamoDBGrainStorage.SHMS.Grains.UserIdentifierGrain during WriteState for grain Type=SHMS.Grains.UserIdentifierGrain Pk=*grn/63F3ADE9/000000000000000000000000000000000600000063f3ade9+user@senmos.dk-0x8999D4D2 Id=GrainReference:*grn/63F3ADE9/00000000+user@senmos.dk Error=

      Exc level 0: Orleans.Storage.InconsistentStateException: Invalid grain state
         at Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage.<WriteStateAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Orleans.Core.StateStorageBridge`1.<WriteStateAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
      Exc level 1: Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
         at Orleans.Persistence.DynamoDB.DynamoDBStorage.<UpsertEntryAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
         at Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage.<WriteStateInternal>d__22.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage.<WriteStateAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
      Exc level 2: Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.<GetResponseAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.<InvokeAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
      Exc level 3: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.<GetResponseAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
InconsistentStateException: Invalid grain state Expected Etag= Received Etag= Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model.ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.<GetResponseAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.<GetResponseAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.<InvokeAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Orleans.Persistence.DynamoDB.DynamoDBStorage.<UpsertEntryAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage.<WriteStateInternal>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Orleans.Storage.DynamoDBGrainStorage.<WriteStateAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
```

Is there any known bugs with DynamoDB or any way I can trouble shoot this further to get more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the anything more specific about the dynamodb errors, but it seems to be caused by the silo freezes.

Apparently the freezing silo command prompt was because of Quick edit mode:
https://serverfault.com/questions/314194/why-does-windows-command-prompt-stalls-until-a-key-is-pressed-when-executing-lon

Disabling quick edit mode seems to have solved my problems.